# Node PHP function causing CRON not to run properly

Tags: entities

Below is my code. I have two fields.

By default, "$staticPath" equals the path of the "field_static_ad" field, and "$flashPath" equals the path of the "field_flash_ad" field.

However, when there is nothing uploaded to "field_flash_ad", I want "$flashPath" to equal the path of "field_static_ad" instead.

This code WORKS for me know, but something is going wrong when I run CRON! I don't get an error, but I can't index my site.

```
<?php
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {  $nid = $node->nid; }

$staticPath = file_create_url($node->field_static_ad['und'][0]['uri']);

$flashPath = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_flash_ad');

if ($flashPath) { $flashPath = file_create_url($node->field_flash_ad['und'][0]['uri']); }

else { $flashPath = file_create_url($node->field_static_ad['und'][0]['uri']); }
?>
```

Is there something wrong with my php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [debug_cron](https://drupal.org/project/cron_debug) module to debug the cron issue.Also I am not sure if the mentioned code is even executing on cron run.
This module provides debugging of

```
 fail due to programming or runtime errors
 time out (PHP, server, database)
 are very slow
```

> Cron Debug will also allow you to test run specific cron functions
>   while not running others. This can be nice for developing cron
>   functions where you don't want to run a full cron.php with all
>   maintenance, alerts and other tasks every time you test your own
>   function.

Also why not you putting the complete code inside the first if conditions like'

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {  
  $nid = $node->nid; 
  $staticPath = file_create_url($node->field_static_ad['und'][0]['uri']); 
  $flashPath = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_flash_ad'); 
  if ($flashPath) {
    $flashPath = file_create_url($node->field_flash_ad['und'][0]['uri']); 
  } else {
      $flashPath = file_create_url($node->field_static_ad['und'][0]['uri']);
   }
}
```

Comment: I needed to be putting the code inside my first if statement like you said :).

Comment: is your issue fixed now?